# Are objects created by GMP for intermediate computations persisted in memory?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, cryptography, gmp

I'm trying to use GMP 6.2.1 as a backend for computations with long integers for cryptography. There it is considered best practice not to leave any traces of sensitive computations longer than needed. Consequently, I wanted to make sure that GMP does not leave anything in memory, but couldn't find anything about it in the docs.

Am I correct to assume that there are two possible sources of unwanted values persisting in memory:

1. Reallocations of numbers into larger sections of memory. Might happen due to self-allocation, for example `mpz_mul (x, x, x);`.
2. Intermediate computations inside GMP functions, which are somehow related to operands or outputs of these functions.

While it seems that reallocations can be avoided by correctly designing the client code, intermediate variables bother me, at least those that are allocated on the heap. Are there any explicit guarantees given by GMP in this respect?

Comment: You can 1) tell gcc not to use alloca (--disable-alloca) and 2) redefine (mp_set_memory_functions) the allocation functions to provide your own clearing version.

Comment: https://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions#Low_002dlevel-functions-for-cryptography

Comment: @MarcGlisse thanks, I don't know how I missed your last link, but it seems to be exactly what I need. Can we make it an answer?

Comment: @MarcGlisse do you have any idea why would there be only one high-level wrapper of these functions: `powm_sec` for modular exponentiation? Is it simply because modular exponentiation is a popular target for side channel attacks? I guess other `mpn_sec_` methods can be similarly wrapped using `powm_sec` as a template?

Comment: No idea. Maybe it is a left-over from before realizing that it was better to provide lower-level functions for this purpose.

Comment: It is hard to implement secure against the side channels, See [bearssl](https://bearssl.org/constanttime.html) and [Efficient function/algorithm/method to do modular exponentiation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75419/18298)

Comment: https://gmplib.org/devel/sec

Comment: @kelalaka It's clear that designing a side-channel secure mod exp is not trivial. Was just wondering why there are no other high-level `mpz_sec` arithmetic operations. Thanks for the links though.

Comment: That is not the aim of the library. The compiler and the target architecture can change all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GMP provides some [low level functions for cryptography](https://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions#Low_002dlevel-functions-for-cryptography), which in particular give you control over allocations.

For higher level functions, you don't get any guarantee, but you could still improve over the default through [custom allocation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Custom-Allocation), and by configuring [temporary allocations](https://gmplib.org/manual/Build-Options#index-alloca).